# AS3 & MySQL - Adding outputted string to variable

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

Im quite sure there is a very simple fix to my problem, but i will explain in as much detail as possible anyway.

Basically im using PHP with MySQL to send information to my flash file using GETs.

Using FlashVars i have managed to get the users 'id' with this i can send my questions/searches to a PHP script which access the database and returns the information to the html page.

What i would like to do now is add the information sent back to the html page to a variable inside flash for example:

```
var usr_name = get_user_name(id) || 'Unknown'; // "Unknown" should just be for offline use.
```

but this just returns 'Unknown'

this is the function used:

```
        public function get_user_name(usr_id){
                loadData('search.php',"quest=name",'usr_id='+usr_id);
        }

private function loadData(page_Name='search.php',get1='g1=1',get2='g2=2',get3='g3=3'):void {
            var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000));
            var create_URL = (URL + page_Name + randomParam + '&'+ get1 + '&' + get2 + '&' + get3) ;
            trace(create_URL);

            _loader = new URLLoader();
            _request = new URLRequest(create_URL);          
            _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
            _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
            _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
            _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
            _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
            _loader.load(_request);
        }

public function onLoadData(e:Event):String {
            return(e.target.data);
        }
```

This all seems to works fine its just when i try to do with out the or statement (|| 'Unknown') i get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at App/frame1()
```

If i just type the URL into a web browser i get the name outputed.

Im not sure why this is such a problem.

Thanks
Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function onLoadData(e:Event):String {

            return(e.target.data);
        }
```

If you expect the above function to return the response string into the variable, then you are wrong.

You have to let the `onLoadData` to fill the variable itself. Try this way:

```
var usr_name = 'Unknown'; 

get_user_name(id);


function get_user_name(usr_id) {

    loadData('search.php',"quest=name",'usr_id='+usr_id);
}

function loadData(page_Name='search.php',get1='g1=1',get2='g2=2',get3='g3=3'):void {

    var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000));
    var create_URL = (URL + page_Name + randomParam + '&'+ get1 + '&' + get2 + '&' + get3);
    trace(create_URL);

    _loader = new URLLoader();
    _request = new URLRequest(create_URL);
    _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.load(_request);
}

function onLoadData(e:Event) {

    usr_name = e.target.data;
}
```

Comment: So this kinda of works, but as there is a delay between the loading and output it grabs the Unknown then once loaded changes it to the name but its already to late..

Comment: The will obviously occur. You are making a request over the network. It doestn't have to be too late. Just make sure nothing else starts until the response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

ok, from a cursory glance at your code, it is obvious you don't know the "asynchronous" nature of URL requests in AS3.

When you do `_loader.load()`, Flash actually opens this pipeline on a different *thread*, so to speak. This ensures that the application does not freeze when URL requests are loading.

All you need to so is something like this:

```
public function get_user_name(usr_id){
    loadData('search.php',"quest=name",'usr_id='+usr_id);
}

private function loadData(page_Name='search.php',get1='g1=1',get2='g2=2',get3='g3=3'):void {
    var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000));
    var create_URL = (URL + page_Name + randomParam + '&'+ get1 + '&' + get2 + '&' + get3) ;
    trace(create_URL);

    _loader = new URLLoader();
    _request = new URLRequest(create_URL);          
    _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
    _loader.load(_request);
}

public function onLoadData(e:Event):String {
    usr_name = e.target.data || 'Unknown';
}
```

And you call it like

```
var usr_name = "";
get_user_name();
```

I've noticed your code is not strongly typed. i.e. you dont assign data types to your variables. This could cause problems and also decreases readability.

Also, you'd be better off removing all the event listeners you added (use `removeEventListener`) so that the loader is garbage-collected.

Comment: Duplicating an answer is not something we should follow at SO... just my thoughts.

Comment: Ah, but I haven't duplicated your answer. The code will __OBVIOUSLY__ be the same, but you have just spoonfed the OP and I have explained why it works the way it does. All in all, that is not called duplicating, so your argument is invalid....just my thoughts.